# Changing HTML codes to HTML through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Within my HTML, I have to change a "-" to a carriage return (`<br />`). I have to achieve that through jQuery.

### Hence, for my following HTML:-

`First sentence - Second Sentence`

### I did this:-

```
caption = caption.replace("-", "<br /><br />");
$('.jcarousel-caption').text(caption);
```

### Result:-

`First Sentence &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; Second Sentence`

I even tried to change my jQuery to:-

```
caption = caption.replace("-", "<br /><br />");
caption.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>').replace('&quot;','"');
$('.jcarousel-caption').text(caption);
```

But it still shows the same output.

I want to achieve this:

`First sentence 
Second Sentence`

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/html/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML. Consider the following HTML:

Since you want to print the html content, you need to use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) not [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('.jcarousel-caption').html(caption);
```